# The quotient of a superspecial abelian surface by the involution

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties, algebraic-surfaces, k3-surfaces

Let $E_i\!: y_i^2 = f(x_i)$ be two copies of a supersingular elliptic curve over a field of odd characteristics. Consider the involution
$$
i\!: E_1\times E_2 \to E_1\times E_2,\qquad (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2) \mapsto (x_2, -y_2, x_1, -y_1)
$$
and the quotient $S := E_1\times E_2/i$.
Is it a K3 surface? What is (are) its defining equation(s)?